# Image not copied to the location specified in python

Tags: python

I am trying to extract images from  a location to (mysql) ID  location, it creates the folders according to the mysql table  ID  but no images are copied.( extracting images from one location and copying them on the ID location)

here is my script.

```
import datetime
import sys
import os
import MySQLdb

db_driver = "mysql"
host = "localhost"
db = "customer_1"
user = "root"
passwd = "H0t"

db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='H0t', db='customer_1')
cursor = db.cursor()

cam_name = sys.argv[1]
topLevel = "/var/wwwdev/cam_images/%s_anpr_vega" % cam_name

sql = """select id,image FROM %s_anpr_vega WHERE image IS NOT NULL LIMIT 20000""" % cam_name
print sql
cursor.execute(sql)
retval = cursor.fetchall()
for values in retval:
    (id, image) = values
    id_string = "%s" % id
    path_string = ""
    for i in range(len(id_string)):
        path_string = "%s/%s" % (path_string, id_string[i])

    imdir = "%s%s" % (topLevel, path_string)
    try:
        os.makedirs(imdir)
    except:
        pass

    image_path = "%s.jpg" % imdir
    print image_path
    fp = open(image_path, "w")
    fp.write(image)
    fp.close();
    sql = """UPDATE %s_anpr_vega SET image=NULL WHERE id=%s""" % (cam_name, id)
    print sql
    cursor.execute(sql)

sql = """OPTIMIZE TABLE %s_anpr_vega """ % cam_name
print sql
#cursor.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this isn't just creating image files named ".jpg" in each folder?

It looks to me like you forgot the filename portion of your `image_path`. You should see that in the prints coming out of that code.

If you're using Windows Explorer or the like you might not notice the dot-named JPEG files.

Comment: Or print image as base64
Or content type jpg for picture_server.py

Comment: @pretyv5 And what is it printing for the `image_path`?

Comment: I get this errror when trying to print.... File "./extract_cam_images.py", line 19, in <module>
    cam_name = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @pretyv5 You forgot to give it the cam name as a command line argument. And there's no way it's creating folders for you if it dies way up there.

Comment: sudo ./extract_cam_images.py  BerkeleyIN
select id,image FROM BerkeleyIN_anpr_vega WHERE image IS NOT NULL LIMIT 20000
OPTIMIZE TABLE BerkeleyIN_anpr_vega this is what I get when i pass the cam name in command line